# Web API - Detecting Client Domain

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain, referrer

I am building a bunch of Web Services using C# and the Web API. The services will be accessible from multiple web apps, and multiple native apps.  The application manages a list of authorized domains, and a list of authorized app ID's (to be used with native apps).

I am looking for a way to detect the domain a web app is being hosted on, so that I can compare that domain name against my list of authorized domains.  So far, the only properties I can find in the request context are properties which define what domain the client/web app is calling, which is not what I want.

For example:
If an app is hosted on externalapp.com, and is making a request to my api on api.myawesomeapi.com, I want to know that the client is hosted on externalapp.com.  But when reviewing the request data, the only information I am find is stuff saying that the client is requesting a resource on "api.myawesomeapi.com".

I expect requests coming from a native app (android, iOS, etc) to not have a client domain, and requests coming from a web app to have a client domain. (client domain, host domain, whatever it should be called).

I have looked at other posts on stackoverflow, and found recommendations to use: Request.Headers.Referrer.  In my case, all the web apps are null and the native app is also null.  This doesn't appear to be an option for me.

Comment: Are you aware that any kind of information about the request (like the `Referrer` header) may be easily (**very** easily) forged/faked by a malicious user? I do not believe that this restriction is secure at all, and if not secure, it is also not useful. Try to review your design and, if you really need to secure your API, use a secure and tested protocol like OAuth2.

Comment: I am very aware of that.  It is one my primary concerns.  I have considered OAuth2, but was hoping for a different solution.

Comment: Even if the values are in the headers, clients can lie (and you should pretty much never trust anything they send). I think you probably do want some kind of authentication you can tie to a client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var referrer = Request.Headers.Referrer;
if (referrer!=null)
{
    string client = referrer.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
}
```

Comment: Is it always accurate?